# A reboot was triggered from inside the virtual machine

Tags: azure

I had an Azure VM whenever I clicked on start it is stopping automatically after some time when I run diagnose it is showing this error "A reboot was triggered from inside the virtual machine. This could be due to a virtual machine operating system failure or as requested by an authorized user or process. The virtual machine will be back online after the reboot completes" Plz let me know if you need any further inforamtion

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you checked the event log to see why the machine is rebooting? Please let us know what you have done so far to investigate the issue